# Calling a Python subroutine at the precise instant when clock seconds value changes?

Tags: python, kivy, schedule, timing

In my app I display a clock. The string representing time is updated once a second when the seconds number changes. I do this by polling the system clock to generate a 'seconds' property. A change in the value of this property triggers a screen update (done with Kivy property bindings). Here is example code that works.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import datetime


Builder.load_string('''
#: kivy 1.9.2

<MainWidget>:
    Label:
        text: root.text
        font_size: 50

''')


class MainWidget(BoxLayout):

    text=StringProperty() # this can be bound to 'text' property of a child widget for observation
    seconds=StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(seconds=self.update_text)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.poll_datetime, .1)

    def poll_datetime(self, dt):
        self.seconds=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S")

    def update_text(self, *args):
        self.text=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        #print "updating text"


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mw=MainWidget()
        return mw


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This seems like an inefficient and inelegant trade-off (timing accuracy vs cpu load). Is there a way to schedule something not just once a second, but once a second at the precise(ish) time the seconds roll over to the next value?

Comment: I'm not sure how to align it with your functionality. But you can schedule functions to be run every second using the schedule library. `schedule.every(1).seconds.do(foo)` and then 

`while True:    
    schedule.run_pending()    
    time.sleep(0.01)`

Comment: You just need to do `Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_text, .1)`. The `poll_datetime` is redundant. As for the precision, it would be quite precise, since the 1sec interval is going to make the offset of the change always the same.

Comment: @Nathan Thank you for your suggestion to use Schedule module but I'm afraid this does not meet the requirement of alignment with actual seconds value rolling over. The possibility will be there that the actual time does not change between consecutive samples, or conversely, advances by 2 seconds instead of one. That is the point of oversampling at .1 seconds in my code

Comment: @embryo Thanks, I realise that - my example code is somewhat contrived to demonstrate the problem. In my actual app the cpu load of `update_text` is much higher than that of `poll_datetime`.